# SSR Angular Universal Server Error when accessing route

Tags: angular, url-routing, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, internal-server-error

I have an Angular 10 application with Angular Universal for SSR and every time I try to directly access an URL i get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Check server side logs

Comment: Can you provide the steps you did to setup your project? Can you provide your code through Github? What backend technology are you using: ASP.NET Core? If so, check if messages are showing up in the Output Window in Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @PRANSHUMIDHA yes, i have a guard that was using localstorage which is not available on server side. So I had to "mock it".